# Why do multiple nested objects appear in this ElasticSearch query?

Tags: database, elasticsearch

In Case 4 of [this page](https://voormedia.com/blog/2014/06/four-ways-to-index-relational-data-in-elasticsearch),  the query searches for all chairs less than 70 units in height:

[image: some data]

```
curl localhost:9200/example/product/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "chair"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "numeric_range": {
          "size.height": {
            "lt": 70
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Result:

```
  "hits": [
    {
      "_id": "0",
      "_source": {
        "product": "chair",
        "size": [
          {
            "width": 50,
            "height": 50,
            "depth": 50
          },
          {
            "width": 75,
            "height": 75,
            "depth": 75
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

1) why is the ID 0 for both chair sizes?

2) why does the response show dimensions for the other chair that is 75 units in height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The writer wanted to show 1 to N relation. Meaning there are 2 (In this case) types of chairs in his repository: A chair with dimensions of 50 and a chair with dimensions of 75. But both of them are still chairs and the id of a chair is 0.

2) Because by default ES doesn't return partial results, it returns documents. In our case we have a chair document with a size array which holds 2 objects: One for the 50 dimension and one for the 75 dimension. The supplied query can either select the whole document or not.

If you want to convert the query to English you may say: Bring me all the documents which have the value "chair" in the product field and at least one of its size.height values is lower than 70.

Even though the writer of the article is knowledgeable, I must say I don't like this kind of articles that trying to draw a direct flow between the SQL world to NOSQL implementation. If it was so easy, some big company would have write an automatic script that converts your SQL schemas to various NOSQL formats. In order to model your data correctly in NOSQL you must understand your products, understand the factors that should influence on your decision, understand the use case and the data. There is no one universal solution that will tell you: If you did it this way in a RDBMS do it like this in ES.

Comment: Is that valid data - duplicate ID values?  Secondly if the ID values for 'chair' differed, then I would expect only one chair document to be returned, rather than two, correct?

Comment: 1. Regarding your expectation in case you would have 2 different id values in two different documents than the answer is yes, You could expect only one document to return.

2. There is no real duplication of the 0 id. In ES you can't have the same id for different documents in the same index/type. What you have is a document with id 0 (A single document) that holds an array with 2 object of dimensions. There is just one ES document that represent two different chair objects.